# Jackson - omitting field names at serialization

Tags: java, jackson

I have the following data:

```
{ long x; long y;}
```

Upon serialization to JSON using Jackson, I get the following:

```
{ "x": 1, "y": 2 }
```

However, I'm looking for this instead:

```
[1, 2]
```

How can I do that with Jackson?

Answer (score 3):

As others have noted you can not omit keys for JSON Objects, but you could serialize POJO as an array like so:

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.ARRAY)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "x", "y" }) // important; or 'alphabetic=true'
public class POJO {
   public int x, y;
}
```

which would then serialize as something like:

```
[1,2]
```

and even deserialize back from JSON Array similarly.

Comment: I am using jackson 1.9.8. JsonFormat is not available. Is there any alternate way.

Comment: Custom serializer. 1.9.x has not been developed for years now, so the feature set is much smaller compared to 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

No, you're violating the JSON format which is essentially key-value format.

However you could serialise it as:

```
{
    values: [ 1, 2 ] 
}
```

Just make it a list in your dto.

Answer (score 0):

```
{ 1, 2}
```

is not a valid JSON. Are you looking for [ 1,2] ? it's list or array. You can serialize

```
List<Long>
```

to it.

Comment: Its my bad. I am looking for [1,2]